# Objective Sharpie binding error: Could not find a part of the path "/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSObjCRuntime.h"

Tags: xamarin, quickblox

I'm trying to bind a Quickblox iOS SDK to Xamarin, but I'm getting the following error:

> Could not find a part of the path "/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSObjCRuntime.h".

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I was suggested at http://forums.xamarin.com/, I installed XCode Command-line tools and now the binding is in progress, I no longer receive this error.

Answer (score 1):

Do you use this guide?

http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/binding_objective-c_libraries

We need advice from guys from Xamarin team how to fix this, hope they read stackoverflow too :)

Comment: Thanks Igor, they have answered my question, the binding has been in progress for several hours by now.:) Hope it will end successfully.