# Xamarin - Objective Sharpie - Error

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin

This is the error I get when I use Objective Sharpie to create a binding of native Objective C static library.

Followed the instructions from [here](http://pierceboggan.com/post/51671827932/binding-third-party-objective-c-libraries-in) and [here](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/binding_objective-c_libraries/objective_sharpie).

sharpie-clang-parser exited with error code: 132
System.Exception: sharpie-clang-parser exited with error code: 132
  at Sharpie.ObjC.Parser.Parse (System.IO.TextWriter sexpWriter, System.Collections.Generic.List`1 stderrLines) [0x00000] in :0 
  at Sharpie.Mac.MainWindowController+c_*AnonStorey3.<>m*_B (System.Object o) [0x00000] in :0

Using
Xamarin Studio 4.0.9 (build 12)

Objective Sharpie v 0.4.9

---Update---

The Xamarin docs, clearly state that Command Line Tools need to be installed before using the Objective Sharpie. This solved the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before using the Objective Sharpie, The command line tools need to be installed in Xcode -> Preferences -> Downloads pane.
This solved the error/issue am facing.

Perhaps this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16731613/344798) helped me.